# How To start application after click push notification kotlin android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdenN.png)

How To start application after click push notification kotlin android studio

i want start my app after click push notification

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `PendingIntent` on **notification builder** like below:

create `activityIntent` and add Activity name that you want to open(here is`MainActivity`)

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Now create **pending intent**:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            this,  // calling from Activity
                            0,
                            appActivityIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now add this `pendingIntent` to your **notification builder**

```
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Note : I have only written the pending intent code because it's only missing in your code. I assume you have all the required code like notification builder